# How to generate tangles?

Tags: knot-theory, programming

In my research I need to generate tangle diagrams for with small number of crossings ($\leqslant 10$).

By tangle I mean 2-tangle, that is an embedding of two arcs into a ball where endpoints of arcs lie on sphere. Tangle diagram is a projection of a tangle to a plane, where the intersections are remembered (like in knot diagrams).

In other words, I need a program that generates 2 arcs in a circle (or a square) with overlappings.

Example:

[image]

Actually, for my purposes I don't need the overlappings, so the program generating tangles diagrams without overlappings would also suffice.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Here is a list of all of them. http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Rolfsen_Knot_Table

Comment: But it is a list of knots, I need to get tangles instead.